# What is setting the JQuery grid's row count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery mobile buttons within a grid, within a container (the container is required to also hold a map which I have removed from displayed code here for brevity.)

I only require 29 buttons in a 2 column grid, so with a maximum row count of 15.

However the grid is seemingly automatically setting at 16 rows and I can't see why.

- I have played around with removing buttons and the rows stay at 16 in number.
- If I add buttons to a block, the row count will increase beyond 16
- In desperation I've tried fiddling with the box size; no effect
- My searches on stackflow and beyond only render queries on how to obtain a count of rows for a grid: indicating that it is jQuery that is setting the rows, not the code.

JSfiddle is:
https://jsfiddle.net/everare/uqkds374/

Code:

```
<DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS file -->
    <!--JQuery links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <!--Link to google fonts-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://ufonts.com/fonts/samarkan-normal.html' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Style Body, Container, Box one-->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: white;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 0px;
        }
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 140px;
            left: 60px;
            border: 0px;
            height: 600px;
            width: 1100px;
            align-content: space-between;
            justify-content: space between;
            margin: 50px background-color: #34495e;
        }
        div.boxOne {
            position: absolute;
            top: 70px;
            left: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 10px solid black;
            border-color: black;
            Width: 415px;
            Height: 510px;
            color: white;
        }
        div.boxTwo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border: 8px solid black;
            border-color: black;
            background-color: black;
            Width: 415px;
            Height: 60px;
        }
        .ui-content {
            padding: 2px 2px;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
            margin-left: 0 !important;
            line-height: 0px;
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .ui-btn-f {
            color: black;
            overflow: visible;
            padding-left: 0px !important;
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            border-radius: 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0px;
            background: black;
            background-color: black !important;
            border: none;
        }

        .ui-btn-text {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Montserrat;
            text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #000;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: white;
        }

        h3 {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Montserrat;
            text-shadow: 0 0px 0 #000;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="boxTwo">
            <h3>
                Indian states
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="boxOne">
            <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <!--Panel for AP-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel1">
                            <h2>Andhra pradesh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>
                            <p>Facts about AP</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Andhra pradesh</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--Panel for AR P-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel2">
                            <h2>Arunachal Pradesh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Arunachal Pradesh</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel2" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Arunachal Pradesh</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for AS-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel3">
                            <h2>Assum</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Assum</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel3" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Assum</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for BI-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel4">
                            <h2>Bihar</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Bihar</p>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel4" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Bihar</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for CH-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel5">
                            <h2>Chhattisgarh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Chhattisgarh</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel5" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Chhattisgarh</span></a>
                        </div>

                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for GO-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel6">
                            <h2>Goa</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Goa</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel6" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Goa</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for GU-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel7">
                            <h2> Gujarat</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about  Gujarat</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel7" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Gujarat</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for HA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel8">
                            <h2>Haryana</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Haryana</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel8" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Haryana</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for HA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel9">
                            <h2>Himachal Pradesh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Himachal Pradesh</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel9" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Himachal Pradesh</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for JK-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel10">
                            <h2>Jammu and Kashmir</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Jammu and Kashmir</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel10" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Jammu and Kashmir</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for JH-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel11">
                            <h2>Jharkhand </h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Jharkhand </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel11" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Jharkhand</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for KA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel12">
                            <h2>Karnataka</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Karnataka</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel12" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Karnataka</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for KE-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel13">
                            <h2>Kerala </h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Kerala </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel13" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Kerala </span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for MP-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel14">
                            <h2>Madhya Pradesh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Madhya Pradesh </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel14" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Madhya Pradesh</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">

                        <!--Panel for MA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel15">
                            <h2>Maharashtra</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Maharashtra </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel15" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Maharashtra</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for MAN-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel16">
                            <h2>Manipur</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Manipur </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel16" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Manipur</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for ME-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel17">
                            <h2>Meghalaya</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Meghalaya </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel17" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Meghalaya</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for MI-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel18">
                            <h2>Mizoram</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Mizoram </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel18" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Mizoram</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for NA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel19">
                            <h2>Nagaland</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Nagaland </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel19" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Nagaland</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for OD-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel20">
                            <h2>Odisha</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Odisha </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel20" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Odisha</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for PU-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel21">
                            <h2>Punjab</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Punjab </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel21" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Punjab</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for RA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel22">
                            <h2>Rajasthan</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Rajasthan </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel22" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Rajasthan</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for SI-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel23">
                            <h2>Sikkim</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Sikkim </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel23" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Sikkim</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for TA-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel24">
                            <h2>Tamil Nadu</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Tamil Nadu </p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel24" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Tamil Nadu</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for TN-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel25">
                            <h2>Telangana</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Telqanaga</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel25" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Telangana</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for TR-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel26">
                            <h2>Tripura</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Tripura</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel26" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Tripura</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for UP-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel27">
                            <h2>Uttar Pradesh</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Uttar Pradesh</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel27" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Uttar Pradesh</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for UT-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel28">
                            <h2>Uttarakhand</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about Uttarakhand</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel28" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">Uttarakhand</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->
                        <!--Panel for WB-->
                        <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel29">
                            <h2>West Bengal</h2>
                            <a href="#mypageone" data-rel="close">Close</a>
                            <p>Facts about West Bengal</p>
                        </div>

                        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                            <a href="#myPanel29" class="ui-btn ui-btn-f"><span class="ui-btn-text">West Bengal</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--End panel-->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your row counts are actually 15. 

Your div (id="pageone") has set min-height of 761px. I am not sure who sets it up but if you lower it down to 696 px it will look good. If you inspect element of the grid, you'll see that it doesn't go much more as it looks like.
The problem is not rows count but the container being bigger than the grid.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  I'm afraid I can't see how to apply the advice.  I think I've only set the height for boxes one and two to meet the height of the container (with room for thick borders).  Do you mind detailing to code change required?